# Set adapters only once at onViewCreated() with ViewModel and NavigationComponents

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewmodel, android-architecture-navigation

I have been reading about [viewmodel-savedstate](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate) , my use case is the following , I inflate a recyclerview and populate it with data, I'm using ConcatAdapter and since I need to construct my view in order I initialize the adapters in my onViewCreated, this just works fine when startup, but if I go from FragmentA to FragmentB and come back , it will pass again to the onViewCreated() hence it will recreate my adapters , repopulate the recyclerview with duplicate items, is there a way to set these adapters just once ? is savedStateHandle a good approach ?

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val firstAdapter = FirstAdapter(listOfData)
        val secondAdapter = SecondAdapter(listOfData)
        val thirdAdapter = ThirdAdapter(listOfData)

        concatAdapter.addAdapter(firstAdapter)
        concatAdapter.addAdapter(secondAdapter)
        concatAdapter.addAdapter(thirdAdapter)
    }
```

So whats happening is, I'm inflating this in FragmentA, thats fine, when I go to fragment B from Fragment A and comes back this will be recreated and also duplicated in my recyclerview

I tried with `concatAdapter.getAdapters().clear()` but I cant clear the list before setting it because is a `unmodifiableList`

How do I do this setup only once at my Fragment or just recreate it from scratch each time I come back to it ?

Comment: Why are you getting duplicate items? That has nothing to do with your adapters and everything to do with how you load your lists of data - that's what you need to fix.

Comment: I'm clearing the data list before seting it at my observers, thats the weird part

Comment: The thing is that coming back from FragmentB will trigger concatAdaper.addAdapter(adapter) again, and this will add an extra view to the recyclerview, making it with duplicate items @ianhanniballake

Comment: The old `RecyclerView` is destroyed and everything related to it should also be destroyed (the adapter, for instance, keeps a hard reference to the `RecyclerView`, meaning it is a memory leak if you keep it around). Are you trying to reuse the same `concatAdapter` instance?

Comment: The instance is created in the onCreate() , I really dont know what is happening

Comment: There you have it !! thanks @ianhanniballake , the problem was indeed keeping a hard reference of the adapter, that will be reused when this fragment is recreated instead of having a new fresh reference to it, it was also causing problems in one of the adapters because it seemed like the adapter not keeped one of the nested adapters reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time `onViewCreated()` is called, you need to create a new `ConcatAdapter` instance for your new `RecyclerView` instance.

The previous `RecyclerView` was meant to be destroyed when `onDestroyView()` is called and you must also remove any references to the adapter at that same point to avoid a memory leak (an adapter holds a hard reference to its `RecyclerView`.  You cannot create just a single instance in `onCreate()` and reuse that over and over again.

By creating a new `ConcatAdapter` instance, you ensure that `addAdapter` is called just once for each of your first, second, and third child adapters.